# formatter.dateFormat = "????"

Tags: xcode, swift, дата

Народ, подскажите есть

```
let currentDate = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM"

self.todayTextLabel.text = formatter.string(from: currentDate)
```

у меня отображается кливое окончание "декабря" как сделать "Декабрь"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()

formatter.dateFormat = "LLLL"
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не додумывайте за автора